# How to prevent Docker from re-running when the only change the Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to make some changes to my Dockerfile and it's causing the build to re-trigger every time. Here is a simplified Dockerfile that I am using:

```
FROM ...

COPY . .

RUN ./build.sh

RUN <other command>
```

I am currently trying to modify everything after `./build.sh` but it keeps getting triggered because the `COPY . .` command and technically the build context has been modified. I have tried adding `Dockerfile` to `.dockerignore`, but this still triggers a rebuild. This wouldn't really be an issue but the build takes upwards of 30 min so it's quite a bit annoying.

I guess I could specify files and folders in the copy such that the Dockerfile is not copied but that could get unwieldy as the number of files and folders grow.

I'm not sure what else to try. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you split the docker file so that your copy & build is separated from the rest?
https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Dockerfile to `.dockerignore` will cause a cache miss on the next build since the Dockerfile is not in the context like it was before. However the next build will not have that issue.

I'd also recommend moving the `COPY . .` as late as possible in the Dockerfile since any context change will trigger a cache miss on that line. So if you have steps later that install dependencies and can run those earlier, and those dependencies rarely change, nice those RUN lines to the top of the file.

Comment: (Hi again) - if one adds a `.dockerignore` mid-dockerfile, is it respected by subsequent steps? Or must it be in position before executing the build?

Comment: The ignore file should be parsed before any build steps are run. And build steps do not have access to modify the host.